# Cannot assign "(<VlanedIPv4Network: 103.35.203.6/31>,)": "IPv4Manage.vlanedipv4network" must be a "VlanedIPv4Network" instance

Tags: python, django

I have a IPv4Manage model:

```
class IPv4Manage(models.Model):
    ...
    vlanedipv4network = models.ForeignKey(
        to=VlanedIPv4Network, related_name="ipv4s", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

And when I update the ipv4 instance:

```
        vlaned_ipv4_network = VlanedIPv4Network.objects.create(
            network_ip = ip_network_divided_obj.network_address.exploded,
            prefix = ip_network_divided_obj.prefixlen,
            gateway_ip = gateway_ip.exploded,
            broadcast_ip = ip_network_divided_obj.broadcast_address.exploded,
            ipv4networkmanage = vlanable_ipv4network.ipv4networkmanage,
        )
        ...
        ipv4 = IPv4Manage.objects.get(ip=ip)
        ipv4.netmask = bits_to_mask(ip_network_divided_obj.prefixlen) 

        if ipv4.ip == gateway_ip:
            ipv4.is_gateway = True
        else:
            ipv4.is_gateway = False
        ipv4.ip_status = IPV4_STATUS.已Vlan化未配置服务器
        ipv4.vlanedipv4network = vlaned_ipv4_network,  # there comes the issue
        ipv4.save()
```

> `Cannot assign "(<VlanedIPv4Network: 103.35.203.6/31>,)": "IPv4Manage.vlanedipv4network" must be a "VlanedIPv4Network" instance.`

[image]

But my `vlaned_ipv4_network` exactly is `VlanedIPv4Network` instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of that line.